# Can't "Browse device" with kdeconnect

Tags: android, kde-connect

When I try and browse my Android device using kdeconnectd by:

1. Right clicking on the kdeconnect-indicator icon in my system tray
2. Click on the dropdown with my phone's name
3. Click on "Browse device"

I get the following error in the console, and nothing happens:

```
$ /usr/lib/kdeconnectd &
...
QDBusAbstractAdaptor: Cannot relay signal SftpPlugin::packetReceived(NetworkPacket): Unregistered input type in parameter list: NetworkPacket
/usr/bin/fusermount: entry for /run/user/1000/850013e6eeea839c not found in /etc/mtab
```

Answer (score 2):

When I type `sshfs` in the console, I also get `zsh: command not found: sshfs`.

Turns out that sshfs is an optional dependency of kdeconnect, but is a required dependency if you want to browse your phone. Installing sshfs fixes the problem.

On Arch Linux, `sudo pacman -S sshfs`.